# rss news aggregator that learns and filters which news articles I find interesting

Tags: web-apps, rss

**Use case**

There are many sites and blogs that occasionally offer interesting articles, but also post many less interesting ones. The user is interested in a specific topic and would like to keep up-to-date on news about the topic, both from specialised news sites/blogs on the topic but also from major news sites. I therefore would like to have a webbased news aggregator/rss reader that allows me to add rss feeds from sites, and shows them so I can read them (so far there are many), but additionally allows me to mark which I find interesting and which I don't find interesting, and learns from that to filter out the uninteresting posts from my rss feeds. Furthermore it would be cool if it would also recommend other rss feeds based on what I marked as interesting (something along the lines of other users which marked similar articles as interesting also read these rss feeds....).

**Requirements**

1. Webbased
2. Aggregates rss feeds
3. Allows the user to mark interesting/uninteresting articles
4. Uses filtering (bayesian or other?) based on interesting articles to only show interesting articles from my rss feeds
5. Recommends new rss feeds based on what I and others marked as interesting
6. A great plus would be having an android app where I can read them as well.

**Costs**

Preferably free.

I hope this is specific enough as a question. Please suggest recommendations if it's not when you downvote.

Comment: Are we talking self hosted or a service?

Comment: Well, both are fine. I was thinking of service, but if there is something similar self hosted exists, that is fine as well.